# Splitting pandas dataframe column (into two) after the first letter in the cell

Tags: python, pandas, string, series

**The problem**

I would like to split a column from a pandas dataframe into 2 columns, in the percentage column (see below), each entry starts with a capitalised alphabet character, I would like to split the 'Percentage' column immediately after this letter, with the new column labelled 'Amino Acid'.

**Current Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')

df['Amino Acid'], df['Percentage'] = zip(*df['Percentage'].map(lambda x: x.split('[^a-zA-Z]')))

df.to_csv('bar.csv',index=False)
```

**Example of input data**

```
+-----------------------------+-------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|           Species           |  ID   | OGT |    DB     |                                         Percentage                                          |
+-----------------------------+-------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Halogeometricum borinquense | 60847 |  37 | ATCC/DSMZ | E is 8.333003365670164% in ./archaea/GCF_000337855.1/GCF_000337855.1_ASM33785v1_protein.faa |
| Halogeometricum borinquense | 60847 |  37 | ATCC/DSMZ | R is 6.310991522830762% in ./archaea/GCF_000337855.1/GCF_000337855.1_ASM33785v1_protein.faa |
| Halogeometricum borinquense | 60847 |  37 | ATCC/DSMZ | A is 10.22668778459711% in ./archaea/GCF_000337855.1/GCF_000337855.1_ASM33785v1_protein.faa |
+-----------------------------+-------+-----+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Example of desired output**

```
+-----------------------------+-------+-----+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|           Species           |  ID   | OGT |    DB     | Amino Acid |                                         Percentage                                         |
+-----------------------------+-------+-----+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Halogeometricum borinquense | 60847 |  37 | ATCC/DSMZ | E          |  is 8.333003365670164% in ./archaea/GCF_000337855.1/GCF_000337855.1_ASM33785v1_protein.faa |
| Halogeometricum borinquense | 60847 |  37 | ATCC/DSMZ | R          | is 6.310991522830762% in ./archaea/GCF_000337855.1/GCF_000337855.1_ASM33785v1_protein.faa  |
| Halogeometricum borinquense | 60847 |  37 | ATCC/DSMZ | A          | is 10.22668778459711% in ./archaea/GCF_000337855.1/GCF_000337855.1_ASM33785v1_protein.faa  |
+-----------------------------+-------+-----+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) be first whitespace:

```
df[['Amino Acid', 'Percentage']] = df['Percentage'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
```

Comment: Do you know how I could also split the string 'archaea' out of the input csv into another column? My input has archaea or bacteria which in that entry

Comment: @Biomage - I think need `df[['before_arch', 'after_arch']] = df['Percentage'].str.split('archaea',n=1, expand=True)`

Comment: Hmm, in my actual input data I also have some 'bacteria' instead of 'archaea' is there a solution that put either result in it's own column?

Comment: @Biomage - do you think split by word `archaea` or `bacteria` ? Then need `.str.split('archaea|bacteria',n=1, expand=True)`

Comment: if I  try: `df['Domain'] = df['Percentage'].str.split('archaea|bacteria',n=1, expand=True)` I get a wrong number of items passed error

Comment: @Biomage - If need string becore splitter `df['Domain'] = df['Percentage'].str.split('archaea|bacteria').str[0]` and if after splitter  `df['Domain'] = df['Percentage'].str.split('archaea|bacteria').str[1]`

Comment: Sorry I think I'm being unclear, the only entry I need in the column is 'archaea' or 'bacteria' so is it possible to be the splitter and retain only the splitter?

Comment: @Biomage - Is possible create data sample and expected output?

Comment: Input is the same as in question, output just has this column as well: `+---------+`
`| Domain  |`
`+---------+`
`| Archaea |`
`| Archaea |`
`| Archaea |`
`+---------+`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174658/discussion-between-biomage-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 10):

You can extract the first letter directly:

```
df['Amino Acid'] = df['Percentage'].str[0]
df['Percentage'] = df['Percentage'].str[1:]
```